# Exponentially distributed variable probability

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

I have a question about a light bulb. It's lifetime is exponentially distributed, with an average of 10,000 hours. 
a.) Calculate the probability that a randomly chosen lightbulb lasts for more than 20,000 hours?

Here I saw 2 ways to do this, and am not sure which is correct. My first result was:
exp(-20000/10000) = exp(-2/1) = 0.135

And my second result:
P(X>20000) = 1-P(X≤20000) = 1-(1-exp(-20000*10000)) = exp(-20000*10000)
= 0

Which of these is the correct way for this?
Also, the next 2 questions were:

(b) What is the probability that a randomly chosen lightbulb lasts for more than
8,000 hours?

(c) Given that a lightbulb has survived for 8,000 hours already, what is the probability it will survive past 20,000 hours?

For (b), would I just do the same as in (a)?
And for (c), because exponential distribution are memoryless, I would do the same but for X>12000?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

You are on the right track, remember that if $X$ is distributed exponentially with parameter $\lambda$, then its PDF is

$$
f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \tag{1}
$$

and CDF is

$$
F_X(x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda x} \tag{2}
$$

The mean is

$$
\langle X \rangle = \color{blue}{\frac{1}{\lambda}} \tag{3}
$$

And there is where your problem is

$$
\langle X \rangle = 10,000~{\rm hours} = \frac{1}{\lambda} ~~~\Rightarrow \lambda = \frac{1}{10,000~{\rm hours}}\tag{4}
$$

So that, the probability that a randomly chosen lightbulb lasts for more than $20,000~{\rm hours}$ is just

\begin{eqnarray}
P(X > 20,000~{\rm hours}) &=& 1 - F_X(20,0000~{\rm hours}) = 1-\left(1- \exp\left(-\frac{20,000~\cancel{\rm hours}}{10,000~\cancel{\rm hours}}\right)\right) \\
&=& e^{-2/1} = e^{-2} = 0.136 \tag{5}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!